# Phonegap facebook plugin errors - cordova cannot be resolved

Tags: android, cordova

I have tried everything to get the phonegap facebook plugin working on android, but to no avail. I am using cordova 3.0. I have followed the instructions at: https://github.com/Raffaello/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/README.md

So the application tag in AndroidManifest.xml looks like:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="face_login" android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>
```

The bottom of the config.xml file looks like:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect" value="org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin" />
    </plugins>
</widget>
```

However, I get a huge amount of errors, such as:

```
CallbackContext cannot be resolved to a type    ConnectPlugin.java

cordova cannot be resolved  ConnectPlugin.java

error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' in package 'android'    AndroidManifest.xml

PluginResult cannot be resolved to a type   ConnectPlugin.java

The import org.apache.cordova.api cannot be resolved    ConnectPlugin.java

webView cannot be resolved or is not a field    ConnectPlugin.java
```

I have included the cordova-3.0.0.jar in the buildpath. But still getting all these errors. Any idea's?

Comment: That plugin hasn't been updated in 6 months so it probably will not run on Cordova 3.x stream without some modification. Try it on a Cordova 2.9 to see it it works? Or you can go through the plugin upgrade docs and try to upgrade it yourself to 3.0.

Comment: Thanks, it works with 2.7. Can you out that as the asnwer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That plugin hasn't been updated in 6 months so it probably will not run on Cordova 3.x stream without some modification.

Try it on a Cordova 2.9 to see it it works?

Or you can go through the [platform upgrade docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides) and try to upgrade it yourself to 3.0. Unfortunately there is not a plugin upgrade guide but there should be.

You could also try to use the [Network Graph page of Github](https://github.com/Raffaello/phonegap-facebook-plugin/network) (I clicked the Fork button) and see if maybe somebody has already ported the plugin to 3.X.

**Edit:** Looks like there is a [fork here](https://github.com/mallzee/phonegap-facebook-plugin/commits/facebook-updates) that has been [updated for 3.0](https://github.com/mallzee/phonegap-facebook-plugin/commit/b3c91c85504a7828dfe8b705065045ae87aeb99d). I have no idea how well it works but I'm sure the author would love pull requests if anything is wrong!