# Facebook Connect + Phonegap 3

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm building an app with Phonegap 3 (it's necessary to be version 3 because Barcode Scanner plugin).

I need to user also Facebook Connect plugin, but there is not already a version for Phonegap 3.

Do you know how can I solve this issue, once I need to offer Facebook Login and Facebook Activites Share for my app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only option you have right now is to update the plugin yourself for version 3.0+ or wait for someone else to do it. Sorry it is not a great answer but it is the only answer at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer about using the Facebook plugin here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19371560/368762

You can try to update the plugin yourself, or if you look on the "Network Graph" on the Github page for the plugin, you can see some forks that other people have been maintaining. One fork says it has been updated to work with 3.0 so I'd suggest that you try that.